# Display First Initial of First name and full Last name

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I want to show in a history of events the first initial of the first name and the full last name.

**Example:**

`let name = "Mike Jones"`

Desired result ---> "M. Jones"

Comment: Have a look at [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`string.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Comment: please make an attempt before asking

Comment: This question does not contain enough research and is very vague. If you would at least try to research a little bit on what you are trying to do, I am certain that you will see some results.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should utilize [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split up the parts of the name, then use [`string.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the first initial, then use [`array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to glue the parts back together.

```js
let name = "Mike Jones" // Who? Mike Jones

// Create an array containing each of the words in the name
var names = name.split(/\s+/);

// Replaces the first name with an initial, followed by a period.
names[0] = names[0].substr(0, 1) + ".";

// Glue the pieces back together.
var name_abbr = names.join(' ');

console.log(name_abbr);
```

Or if you want to get fancy, you could use some regex to get the first letter of the first word, and then everything else, and then just put a period between them.

```js
let name = "Mike Jones" // Who? Mike Jones

var parts = name.match(/^([a-zA-Z])[^\s]*(.*)$/);
var abbr_name = parts[1] + "." + parts[2];

console.log(abbr_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to support multiple initials you could do something like:

```
let name = "Mike Fred Jones"

//string.split() name by [space].

var names = name.split(" ")

//Temporary variable for initialled name.

var newname = ""

//For each name in the names array.
for (n in names){

    //make sure its not the last.
    
    if (String(names[n]).valueOf() != String(names[names.length-1]).valueOf()){
        
        //Append the first letter of the name and [.]
        
        newname = newname + names[n][0] + "." 
        
    }
}

//Append initials, [space], and last name.

newname = newname + " " + names[names.length-1]

console.log(newname) //Outputs M.F. Jones
```